# What's the difference between these two syntaxes

Tags: typescript

In the documentation at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html, the examples use the form such as:

```
import * as lib from "lib"
```

In the templates for a Typescript project in Visual Studio, examples are:

```
import express = require("express");
```

How different are the two?  What does the `require` function do? Is there a definitive specification for the `import` command?

Comment: Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651495/difference-between-import-from-and-import-require-in-typescript