# unable to use write-good npm module in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 8.2.4. I download the npm module write-good. When I try to use in my test component i am getting error ERROR ReferenceError: match is not defined.
Here is the component code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as  writeGood from 'write-good';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-textnpm',
  templateUrl: './textnpm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textnpm.component.css']
})
export class TextnpmComponent implements OnInit {
  testString: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hello();
  }

  public hello() {
    this.testString = writeGood('so so the cat was stolen.');
  }
}
```

Below is the error details,

```
ERROR ReferenceError: match is not defined
    at Object.push../node_modules/weasel-words/weasel.js.module.exports [as fn] (weasel.js:40)
    at write-good.js:101
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at writeGood (write-good.js:97)
    at TextnpmComponent.hello (textnpm.component.ts:18)
    at TextnpmComponent.ngOnInit (textnpm.component.ts:14)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31909)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44366)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44305)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45327)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option of using default method of writeGood

```
public hello() {
    this.testString = writeGood.default('so so the cat was stolen.');
    console.log(this.testString);
  }
```

working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jkxhj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Option 2:** Use below line for importing write-good

import writeGood = require('write-good');

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eaf4o9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Please refer this link for more details on import of javascript librairies with export of a function or class instead of modules or objects

[Difference between `import from` and `import require` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651495/difference-between-import-from-and-import-require-in-typescript)

Comment: Same error. It work on stackblitz even without default method.

Comment: @Waqas, updated my answer with option 2 and with reference link

Comment: While compiling I get the following error ----- error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.