# External JavaScript Library containing require()-statement failed to load into angular 8 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular8

I am using an external javascript library in my angular 8 app containing a require statement at the first place.

`require('dependency')`

However I included the dependency and the other library in the *angular.json* scripts-section.

The problem is that the require-method does not get called or is not known:

`someLibrary.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

So how can I solve this issue in context of angular.

Here are my compiler options too:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs", // <-- value: "es2015" also not solves the issue
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? does this has something to do with this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/4457758

Comment: Is this a custom module or a npm dependency?

Comment: Yes I've installed both pure js-modules/libs the one which is required and the one which includes the require statement via npm install ...

Comment: Import of javascript librairies with export of a function or class instead of modules or objects is the issue for some scenarios

Comment: @ArgV, refer this link for more details- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651495/difference-between-import-from-and-import-require-in-typescript

Comment: Are you calling `require('dependency')` from your TypeScript source code in your Angular app?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by just using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) on the JS file I wanted to be loaded into the browser. Be sure to use the --s command so you can expose your js globally so that your angular app can interface with it.

For example, you might do something like:

```
browserify dependency.js --s myDependency
```